# Why does arm-none-eabi-size report the .data section to be 0 even though I am using initialized RAM?

Tags: c, linker, embedded, arm, binutils

I am a bit confused by the results I am getting when I use my toolchain's (Yagarto and codesourcery) size utility. it is reporting that I am using 0 bytes in the data section. see below

```
$ arm-none-eabi-size.exe rest-server-example.crazy-horse.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  79364       0   34288  113652   1bbf4 rest-server-example.crazy-horse.elf
```

I know my code is using and initializing static RAM variables to values other than 0.

interestingly enough when I pass the size tool directly some of the object files that are getting linked I see .data section being reported

example:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1648       0      20    1668     684 obj_crazy-horse/uip-nd6.o
    200      12    2652    2864     b30 obj_crazy-horse/uip-packetqueue.o
     12       0       0      12       c obj_crazy-horse/uip-split.o
   1816      24      48    1888     760 obj_crazy-horse/usb-core.o
    284       0       0     284     11c obj_crazy-horse/usb-interrupt.o
   2064      20     188    2272     8e0 obj_crazy-horse/xmac.o
```

Why would the elf file report 0 for the .data section when the object files that make it are reporting non-zero values?

FYI I am working on embedded software for a AT91SAM7x256 Micro

edit:

adding the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS

```
CFLAGS  += -O -DRUN_AS_SYSTEM -DROM_RUN  -ffunction-sections

LDFLAGS += -L $(CPU_DIRECTORY) -T $(LINKERSCRIPT) -nostartfiles -Wl,-Map,$(TARGET).map
```

edit #2: 
from the object dump we can clearly see that the .data section has data assigned to it but the size utility is not picking it up for some reason
[objdump link](http://pastebin.com/UfHmJU6t)

All I am looking for is to get an exact usage of my RAM I am not trying to figure out whether one of my variables was optimized out.

edit 3: 
more information showing that the size utility does see something in the .data section

```
$ arm-none-eabi-size.exe -A -t -x  rest-server-example.crazy-horse.elf
rest-server-example.crazy-horse.elf  :
section              size       addr
.vectrom             0x34   0x100000
.text             0x10fc8   0x100038
.rodata            0x149c   0x111000
.ARM.extab           0x30   0x11249c
.ARM.exidx           0xe0   0x1124cc
.data              0x1028   0x200000
.bss               0x7bec   0x201028
.stack              0xa08   0x20f5f8
.ARM.attributes      0x32        0x0
.comment             0x11        0x0
.debug_aranges      0xc68        0x0
.debug_info       0x2b87e        0x0
.debug_abbrev      0x960b        0x0
.debug_line        0x9bcb        0x0
.debug_frame       0x4918        0x0
.debug_str         0x831d        0x0
.debug_loc        0x13fad        0x0
.debug_ranges       0x620        0x0
Total             0x7c4c5
```

Comment: I have also checked the map file and it shows data allocated in the .data regions of memory

Comment: My first guess would be that the sections are being optimized away. Are you compiling/linking with `--gc-sections` and/or `--function-sections`?

Comment: I edited the original post for more visibility but I am using --function-sections. However removing it doesn't change anything for me

Comment: can you show the disassembly if your elf and show where the initialized variable is. and/or post a simple example that demonstrates the problem?  or post the relevent portion of your source code, something.  it sounds like it is optimized away or discarded as dead code for some other similar reason.

Comment: maybe the size util is bad or rounding down or something.  do a disassembly and search for .data.

Comment: I can get a disassembly too but would this be enough? [Header dump](http://pastebin.com/UfHmJU6t). The main

Comment: Are you sure `rest-server-example.crazy-horse.elf` and `project.elf` are the same? I somehow see significant difference between the outputs of `size` and `objdump`. All fields are mis-matching instead of just the data section, the problem area. Just guessing whether its a manual error.

Comment: I am sorry about the confusion. They are the same I just changed the name to project.elf because **rest-server-example.crazy-horse.elf** seemed like too long of a name. I will edit the post to avoid any more confusion

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation would be that the linker script creates a single loadable section, which contains the initial values of the data section and a piece of startup code that copies the data to the uninitialized data section.

This is necessary if you want to have a single image file that can be run from read-only memory, as there is no ELF loader in front then that would perform that copy for you.

Normally, this is only done in the section to segment mapping (i.e. the output sections are arranged in the linker script using the `>` section placement command) rather than by mapping the input section twice, but that is certainly possible as well.

The usage numbers are quite accurate: the text size is the amount of Flash space needed, the BSS size is the amount of RAM needed. Initialized data is counted twice, once for the initial data in Flash, and once for the modifiable data in RAM.

Comment: I am sorry Simon. I am not sure I understand how that explains the reasons why I am seeing size of 0 in my data section.

Comment: Your executable is not going to be loaded as an ELF file, but rather converted to a raw binary image, to be written to flash memory which is going to be readonly during execution. So there are only two possible output section types: initialized/readonly, and uninitialized/read-write. In order to have initialized writeable data, you store the initial values in the initialized space (along with the rest of .text/.rodata), and copy them to writeable space first thing after startup. This is done by the startup code that is automatically linked for you.

Comment: I think I understand your answer. However I don't think it's the answer to my problem. I have used source countrol to go back to my project as it originally started and I must've done something because at one point .data section was not 0

Comment: This might be dependent on the toolchain version.

Answer (score 2):

Your .data section have the CODE attribute set, and this confuses "arm-none-eabi-size". The size of the .data section is incorrectly added to the total text size instead of the data size.

My guess is that you have some code that is stored in flash but is copied to ram at run time such as a fast interrupt handler or flash reprogramming that must run from RAM. This will set the CODE attribute for the data segment, and "size" believes that all of .data is text.

Comment: How can you tell that is the case?

Comment: From the objdump:

Sections:       
  5 .data         00001028  00200000  001125ac  00020000  2\*\*3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, **CODE**